# Does I18n in iPhone app require all these steps?

Tags: iphone, ios, internationalization

I have been able to introduce i18n in an iPhone app and found it a bit hard, so I want to verify that I am doing it correctly.

Is it true that these three steps are required?

- Add a "Localizable.strings" for each language. Used for values in classes.
- Add a "InfoPlist.strings" for each language. Used for the app display name.
- Add i18n for all languages to all xib-files and set correct texts in each seperate xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'm afraid all these steps make your iOS app localizable. However you can skip the third step for xib files that don't include any localizable content.